# Artifactory GO remote not downloading zips

Tags: go, artifactory

I'm using Artifactory 7.10.6.
go version 1.15.6 (also tested with older versions)
I am not using the jfrog cli, and would prefer not to.

I'm trying to sort out what I'm doing wrong here.  I've used Artifactory to pull down content from remote connections to be stored on an local repository for other package types, but this doesn't seem to be working for me fully with GO.  Disclaimer, I'm not super versed in GO...

Here is what I have setup.
a local go repo called "go-ext-release"
a remote of gocenter called "go-gocenter"
a virtual called "go-virtual" that contains only "go-ext-release"
a virtual called "go-virtual-dev" that contains "go-virtual" followed by "go-gocenter"

The idea here of course.  Run a build with my GOPROXY set to "go-virtual-dev", copy the downloaded files from go-gocenter-cache to "go-ext-release".  That should get me all the files I need to reset my environment, point to GOPROXY to "go-virtual" and run a build.

My build pointing to "go-virtual-dev" works fine.  Build works, content is pulled down (mostly .mod and .info).
I move that content to the local (go-ext-release) and build in a clean environment using "go-virtual" and the build fails.  it says it can't access .zip files.  i.e. a 404 on /github.com/gorilla/mux/@v/v1.7.4.zip
Of course when I look for that zip, it doesn't exist.
If I take the url its trying to access and change the url from the "go-virtual" path to "go-virutal-dev" and punch it into a web browser the correct zip file gets downloaded to the "go-gocenter-cache" repo (as expected).
I did this process for the 4 or 5 zip files the build needed (its a small test build), and then moved the zips from the cached location over to the "go-ext-release" repo.  After that, the build works using the "go-virtual" repository (i.e. the repo that just sees into our local repo).

So what am I doing wrong here?  My expectation was that the initial build would have pulled all the files , zips included, to the cache as well.  I know the build pulled them down because I can see them in my GOCACHE folder.  Its as though it isn't using my GOPROXY to pull the zips down

Any help would be appreciated.

is there any commanline switch to force go to show me the exact URL it is using for pulls?  I've experimented with using go get -v, but it doesn't give the full url.

Comment: I hope you've read: https://golang.org/ref/mod#zip-files? PS: Not sure if it's gonna help or not.

Comment: that was helpful in that it confirmed the zip file is being downloaded from my PROXY.  It doesn't explain though why it isn't being retained there...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running the build against `go-virtual-dev` using an empty `GOPATH`. I believe the Go client will not trigger the module zip download if you already have it locally which will not allow Artifactory to cache it from the remote repo.

BTW, Running `go get -x` should show you all the URLs being fetched.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior with the GOPATH not being set. I should not that in all tests the entire system was clean
so I ran a test just calling
go get -x github.com/gorilla/mux@v1.7.4

the log actually has this listed in the output
get https://<url>/artifactory/api/go/go-virtual-dev/github.com/gorilla/mux/@v/v1.7.4.zip
get https://<url>/artifactory/api/go/go-virtual-dev/github.com/gorilla/mux/@v/v1.7.4.zip: 200 OK (0.026s)

when I look in my cache in Artifactory, the zip file isn't there. if I put that url into my browser, then it gets downloaded to my artifactory cache.